# XeLaTex with pgfplots displays wrong color?

Tags: pgfplots, xetex, color

I'm using XeTex for Truetypefonts.

It appears as if the color output in pgfplots is not correct. Is that a bug? Or do I have some misconfiguration?

For other colors than black (e.g. red for the axis line color) it actually works as expected...

My pgfversion: 3.0.1a

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{axis line style=black}
\color{green}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
         \addplot {x*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With XeLaTex:
[image]
Expected behaviour (with pdflatex):
[image]

Comment: Interesting question. I think this could reasonably be seen as a bug in `pgfplots`. I suggest you report it and see. As a workaround, load `xcolor` with an explicit colour model: `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}`.

Comment: Try - `\pgfplotsset{axis line style={color=black}}`

Comment: That works indeed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround. Use

```
\pgfplotsset{axis line style={color=black}}
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the dvipdfmx list and Shunsaku Hirata confirmed my suspicion that it is a dvipdfmx failure. A similar problem can be shown with this smaller example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\special{pdf:bcolor [0]}
\special{pdf:code q 1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}
text in red
\special{color push gray 0} %switch back to black
Text in black.
\special{color pop}
\special{pdf:code Q}
\special{pdf:ecolor}
\end{document}
```

[image]

"Text in black" should be black but is red. The source of the problem is that dvipdfmx doesn't know that the color has been changed to red with the `pdf:code` special - it only keeps track of the color specials - and so assumes that the color has not changed and that it can ignore the `color push gray 0`.

The problem will be resolved in a future version.

https://tug.org/pipermail/dvipdfmx/2019-August/000030.html